# Is there a good way to register the same object twice in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have some feature toggles that I include in my .NET application which uses StructureMap.  I want to register the feature toggles for two purposes.

- Display current state of **all** `IFeatures` on a diagnostic page.
- Use certain instances in constructors of services that rely on given `IFeature` implementations

Here is my setup.  What I'm wondering is, am I doing this right?  Is there a better way I could be doing it?

```
class HotNewFeature : IFeature { ... }

class ServiceThatUsesFeature 
{
    public ServiceThatUsesFeature(HotNewFeature hotNewFeature) { ... }
}

// Type registry setup
For<HotNewFeature>().Singleton().Use<HotNewFeature>();
For<IFeature>().Singleton().Add(c => c.GetInstance<HotNewFeature>);
For<ServiceThatUsesFeature>().Singleton().Use<ServiceThatUsesFeature>());

// Get all instances on the diagnostics page:
IEnumerable<IFeature> features = ServiceLocator.Current.GetAllInstances<IFeature>();
```

I expect that on the diagnostic page, `features` would in this case contain an `IEnumerable` with a single element, the instance of `HotNewFeature`.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what instances you are expecting GetAllInstances to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Scan` feature to register all types that implement IFeature. That will satisfy your first need, to display a list on the Diagnostics page.

If a service needs a specific implementation, it should declare the specific type it needs (`HotNewFeature`) instead of the interface (`IFeature`) in the constructor. You have done this correctly in your example. At that point you do not need to do anything more in StructureMap. If you request `ServiceThatUsersFeature` from StructureMap, and it relies on a concrete class (`HotNewFeature`), StructureMap will know how to instantiate that concrete class.